# Copy-paste for vim is not working when mouse (:set mouse=a) is on?

Tags: vim, clipboard

I was trying to copy paste something from vim to another application and also, from that application to `vim` using right click with mouse and then copy and paste (or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and also tried the <kbd>Command</kbd> version for mac OSX, obviously.). However, when I try doing it, it only copies the first word when I do it from `vim` or when I copy from the application to `vim`, it copies everything, but inserts strange tabs and spaces. I think this happened when I decided to set my mouse on in the terminal. As in:

```
:set mouse=a
```

I have that line on my `.vimrc` file on iTerm (mac os x). Though, is it possible to make my copy paste with other applications that are not in `vim` not to break with the `mouse=a` on? Or is it at least possible to set my mouse off while I do the copy paste? I did `:help` mouse but the comments were not useful for me. I would paste them here but... my copy paste tool is broken!

I did try `:set mouse!` and `:set mouse=a!` but these did nothing useful... :(

---

Additional info of my environment:

I am also using tmux most of the time, though, I tested this error/bug without a tmux session, thats why I posted this mainly as a vim question.

Comment: I can tell you that `vim` is capable of yanking to the Primary Selection just fine using the `y` verb. I don't know why you wouldn't just use that.

Comment: I wouldn't do that because I don't know how to do that I guess, apologize for my incompetence. I didn't even know that existed until you mentioned it. Please share your knowledge! :)

Comment: Is this [macvim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)?

Comment: no it is not its just iTerm (as I mentioned on the question, but good question though).

Comment: @Pinocchio - take a look here: [How to make vim paste from (and copy to) system's clipboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard).

Comment: Do copying and pasting work with other terminal applications?  Also, does it work with vim running in the native OS X Terminal?

Comment: well, the thing is that `:set mouse=a` does not work properly with the native terminal. In fact it doesn't do anything as far as I can tell (so yes, copy pasting does seem to work in the native terminal)

Comment: if I could just `:set mouse=OFF` or something like that, that would be kind of a hack (not a "real" solution), but at least I would be able to copy paste by turning the mouse=off whenever I need to copy paste...

Comment: None of the answers here worked for me, but there are some useful ones [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139578/copy-paste-for-vim-is-not-working-when-mouse-set-mouse-a-is-on) (which work well in Linux at least).

Comment: On macOS: hold "fn" key while selecting!

Comment: @HalosGhost an example is using vim over SSH. Yanking is great for when you want to use the word in Vim itself, but what if I want to copy something to _my_ clipboard (not the clipboard on the host where Vim is running), maybe simply to paste it into a web browser?

Comment: Charlie, I wonder if you could settle something for me? There's been some debate re whether or not your objective was to be able to simply copy & paste - or was your objective to be able to copy and paste ***while using one of the `mouse` commands***? Do you recall that far back?  Thanks - I'll "owe you one"  :)

Answer (score 113):

`mouse=a` prevents the ability of copying and pasting out of vim with readable characters.

Change `mouse=a` to `mouse=r` and that should fix your issue with that.

one thing I am wondering is, are you changing the config file for your vim with the mouse set to mouse=a?

orignal answer ^

If `mouse=r` doesn't give you all the copy past options change it to `mouse=v`

Both `mouse=r` and `mouse=v` have the same functions you are needing, but depending on the vimrc you are using one will work better then the other.

Comment: also have you tryed highlighting the the text and use you mouse middle button to past into another place. that tends to work better when tryng to Ctrl+v and Ctrl+c

Comment: I don't know what your question means: `one thing I am wondering is, are you changing the config file for your vim with the mouse set to mouse=a?` You mean if I have `:mouse=a` on in my .vimrc file? I do have `:mouse=a` in my .vimrc file file.

Comment: that is what I mean. That is my mistake on asking it like that. you need to change it to mouse=x.....

Comment: I did the command `:set mouse=x` in my vim command and it said `E539: Illegal character <x>: mouse=x`, you sure there is such a command? I tried to see if it was an option when I did `help mouse` in vim and nothing came up.

Comment: it is a commmand. But I looked further into it and some people had the same issue. it is due to a patch that disabled `mouse=x`. they made it `mouse=r` instead. I don't know why but thats what they did. i will modify my post to be `mouse=r`

Comment: another thing do you have `--with-x=yes` in your .vimrc file. If this isn't in there a lot of the copy and paste methods don't work properly.

Comment: just `--with-x=yes`? I do not need to put `:set --with-x=yes mouse=a` or something? Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Also, your first suggestion (`:set moutse=r`) solved half the problem, now I can paste from vim to the outside! Though, when I paste back it inserts a lot of extra spaces randomly and it doesn't respect the indentation from the original text... :(

Comment: Let me research if you need to combine `--with-x=yes` to `set mouse=a`. When i was reading up on it all i saw was it was by itself in the config file. But it could be different so I want to make sure that I tell you the right thing that will work for you.

Comment: I have done a lot of research on where `--with-x=yes` needs to be placed. The --with-x=yes is its own stand alone inside the vimrc. But what happened is that mouse=a was supposed to replace that option and make everything work again. But it just has created a big problem for them. Dolby has made posts about it and they came up with a work around to get the old settings that worked right in the first place. you can install the older vim packages like gvim to work with the new ones and it will bring back all the old settings that worked.

Comment: One more thing that I have found out is people are changing the `mouse=a` to `mouse=v` and have all the functions back. Now i know that `mouse=r` works and lets you copy and paste out of the vim file just fine. But change it to `mouse=v` and see if that fixes the rest of the issues you were having when coping into it. A lot of people seem to have the same issue and have sent in bug reports and were told the same thing I said and change it to `mouse=r` or `mouse=v`

Comment: I have also edited my answer so it will be easier to see for everyone else. Hopefully the information I have given you does the trick

Comment: This answer doesn't seem right: `mouse=r` or `mouse=v` disable vim controlling the selection, resulting in line numbers from `set number` to appear in copied text.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this suggestion work like a charm with mouse=v

Answer (score 33):

For OS X users: To copy paste with `mouse=a` use <kbd>alt</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd> to selec the text. Then <kbd>cmd-c</kbd> and <kbd>cmd-v</kbd> work as expected.

Found this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4608387/671639 after a lot of googling.

Comment: You are God...... :')

Comment: For me on OSX works "fn" instead of "shift" or "alt".

Comment: Setting `mouse=v` worked for me with straight `cmd + c`

Answer (score 14):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608161/copy-text-out-of-vim-with-set-mouse-a-enabled/4608387

Press 'shift' key while selecting with the mouse. This will make mouse selection behave as if mouse=a was not enabled.

This works and has been verified by reviewers of stack-overflow who have accepted this as answer :)

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem: could not highlight using the mouse so could not copy and paste from VIM in a terminal session to Windows document and browser:
Did the following and it now works:

```
: set clipboard=unnamedplus
: set mouse=r
```

Comment: Now the colors have disappeared and the backspace doesn't work :/

Comment: @KarlMorrison does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/311451/38036

Answer (score 6):

[Bharath's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186934/33055), pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> while copying, will do it, but it will copy more than what you'd like to copy in-case of numbering or hash comments.

One way to do so even with **mouse=a** is use visual mode by pressing <kbd>V</kbd> for single cursor or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for full line highlight, and you can move up or down with arrows and use <kbd>Y</kbd> to copy or <kbd>D</kbd> to cut and that should work.

Comment: I rephrased your self-pronounced comment to make it more like an answer that way the mods will probably leave it as is (and you might gain some reputation on it so you can comment). If the original had been a more minor correction, commenting would have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Refer: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html

Look at Note section at the bottom of the reference:
 When enabling the mouse, the mouse buttons can still be used by keeping the shift key pressed. This includes copy paste using mouse buttons.

```
*'mouse'* *E538*
'mouse'         string  (default "", "a" for GUI, MS-DOS and Win32)
            global
            {not in Vi}
    Enable the use of the mouse.  Only works for certain terminals
    (xterm, MS-DOS, Win32 |win32-mouse|, QNX pterm, *BSD console with
    sysmouse and Linux console with gpm).  For using the mouse in the
    GUI, see |gui-mouse|.
    The mouse can be enabled for different modes:
        n   Normal mode
        v   Visual mode
        i   Insert mode
        c   Command-line mode
        h   all previous modes when editing a help file
        a   all previous modes
        r   for |hit-enter| and |more-prompt| prompt
    Normally you would enable the mouse in all four modes with:
        :set mouse=a
    When the mouse is not enabled, the GUI will still use the mouse for
    modeless selection.  This doesn't move the text cursor.

    See |mouse-using|.  Also see |'clipboard'|.

    Note: When enabling the mouse in a terminal, copy/paste will use the
    "* register if there is access to an X-server.  The xterm handling of
    the mouse buttons can still be used by keeping the shift key pressed.
    Also see the 'clipboard' option.
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing that reference, but, does it _answer the question_? If so, can you identify the part of the quote that does so, presenting a summary of the actual answer?

Answer (score 3):

Use these two lines below in your `~/.vimrc` to use all nice features of a `gui-mouse` and paste into system clipboard using `y` (yank key) if you don't really need any additional clipboard buffers:

```
set mouse=a
set clipboard=unnamed
```

Answer (score 3):

On my Mac, what helped were those two things:

- :set mouse-=a
- fn+click (instead of shift or alt)

Answer (score 1):

*(Updated as per discussion in comments)*

Ok so just follow these frustrating steps to make vim behave sanely (allow mouse copy and keep syntax highlighting):

**Option 1: 'system-wide'**

1. in `/etc/vimrc`, uncomment `source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim`
2. in `/etc/vimrc.local` add `set mouse=v`
3. for every user that is effected create a a `.vimrc` eg.:

   - `touch ~/.vimrc`
   - `sudo touch /root/.vimrc`

**Option 2: per user**

For every affected user add this to their `~/.vimrc`

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim 
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
set mouse=v
```

---

*More info / rant:*

*I had to play around a lot to figure this out, mainly on debian/mxlinux.
I'm baffled why there is no easier way to configure system-wide defaults without having a .vimrc in each user home :'(*

*Apparently `/etc/vimrc` and `/etc/vimrc.local` are ignored if there is no `~/.vimrc`*
https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2042

*Not having mouse select by default is sooo annoying :'(*

Comment: Any edits to files in `/usr/share/vim/` will be lost when the package is updated. Use something like https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16103/205 instead

Comment: @muru Thanks for mentioning that! So do you know what the right place to edit this is?

Comment: Your `~/.vimrc` is the right place. And then your problem is that if you add it to `~/.vimrc`, the syntax highlighting goes away. That's because `defaults.vim` is not sourced if `~/.vimrc` exists, so you add `unlet! skip_defaults_vim` 
`source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` so the defaults are loaded anyway (put `set mouse=v` after the `source`).

Comment: awesome, thanks @Muru that worked, Maybe post as an answer then I can vote for you

Comment: That's OK, you can upvote https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16103/205, and update your answer to what worked for you

Answer (score 0):

As for the second part of your question where in you specified that when pasting from other applications to vim it adds tabs/spaces. Try adding this to your ~/.vimrc
set paste
or in vim before pasting in normal mode 
press "shift" + ":" and type "set paste"

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>y</kbd> to copy(yank) and <kbd>p</kbd> to paste even with `:set mouse=a` set in `~/.vimrc`. Use <kbd>v</kbd>+`arrow keys` to highlight the text. To copy an entire line quickly, use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>.

Comment: To anyone wondering - `y` won't copy it to the system clipboard. So you can only paste back into vim. Which defeats 50% of the purpose of a clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to add:

1. Be aware many times `set mouse=v` won't work as expected depending on the other directives you have set before or after in your `.vimrc` file, it also depends on which terminal you are running vim from;
2. I would recommend to keep `mouse=a` so you have all the mouse mode enabled at the same time and use the trick proposed by @BHS to highlight text while pressing the Shift key when you need to paste the highlighted text using the middle mouse button ([Copying text outside of Vim with `set mouse=a` enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608161/copying-text-outside-of-vim-with-set-mouse-a-enabled)).